# getting the name of the calling method

Tags: vb.net, reflection

Basically i've got a web service that i'm trying to put some kind of usage logging in.
To do this i've created a class with a logging method.
I instatiate the class on the service and then call the logging method in each of the web methods.

I'm trying to find a way of getting the name of the method that has called the loggong method

```
Public sub tstmethod
log_object.log_method
end sub
```

in this case the returned name i'm looking for is "tstmethod"

Everywhere i've seen has said to either use

```
Dim stackframe As New Diagnostics.StackFrame
Return stackframe.GetMethod.Name.ToString
```

Or to use

```
Dim stackframe As New Diagnostics.StackFrame
Return stackframe.GetMethod.DeclaringType.FullName
```

which i call inside the logging method

getmethod.name.tostring returns the name of the logging method

getmethod.declaringtype.fullname returns the name of the logging class

no matter what i do i cannot find a way of getting the name of the method that called the logging method in this case "tstmethod"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `StackFrame` with an appropriate constructor. For example,

```
Dim stackframe As New Diagnostics.StackFrame(1)
```

will skip one stack frame (the logging method itself) and get the frame for the caller of that method.

That said - if at all possible, I'd strongly recommend using a standard logging mechanism such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html).

Comment: Doesn't work in production

Answer (score 12):

I think the above statement can be made into one single line:

```
MsgBox((New System.Diagnostics.StackTrace).GetFrame(1).GetMethod.Name)
```

This will display a Message Box as with calling method name.

Answer (score 4):

VB.Net

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name()
```

Comment: Won't this just get the name of the current method? I think the OP is asking how to get the name of the method that called the current method.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this from the StackFrame with the constructor telling it how many frames to go up the chain, so getting the parent would use 1 (the frame is zero based, so 0 is the current method):

```
Dim stackTrace as New Diagnostics.StackFrame(1)
Return stackTrace.GetMethod.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not try using StackFrame. It will work only in debug mode which is a killer for application speed.

There is no way you can get this info in Release mode, you should consider changing design and adding parameter.

Comment: There's no need to downvote me - I just pointed out how to make StackFrame work for the questioner, but I specifically recommended using log4net (which works in Release mode as well as Debug mode).

You should only downvote unhelpful answers - by my reckoning, my answer was not unhelpful.

Comment: BTW I wasn't the one to downvote you. I'd never downvote without leaving a comment giving the reason for the downvote.

Comment: BTW, reason was my post. I downvoted all StackFrame posts because this was one month of work to find out why app doesn't work in release mode.

Comment: -1: It does work in release mode (if you modify the project properties to include the pdb)

Comment: I couldn't find this particular setting in project properties. And no informations in MSDN about it. Maybe you mix-up knowledge about C++?

Comment: StackFrame always contains the stack - even in release builds without pdb - the pdb is only needed to get source filename and line number.

Answer (score 0):

I add the calling form as the first parameter for all sub routines and functions 
like calledfunction(me,para1,para2......) so that i can identify the calling form and use its name or text in the called routine

Answer (score -1):

I am using using this code for getting the calling method

```
string methodName = new StackFrame( 1, true ).GetMethod().Name;
methodName = " [" + methodName + "]";
return methodName;
```

remember to add namespace Diagnostics

Comment: Isn't setting `fNeedFileInfo` to `true` (second argument to `StackFrame` constructor) a bit unnecessary in this case?